# my Javascript button doesn't work when I upload the extension to Google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The button works alright on my code editor but when I upload the whole package to chrome extensions the function doesn't fire.

here's the js:

```
const netProfit = document.getElementById("netprofit")
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const gg = document.getElementById("gg")
 
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const buyPrice = document.getElementById("buyprice").value
    const sellPrice = document.getElementById("sellprice").value
    const royalty = document.getElementById("royalty").value
    const serviceFee = document.getElementById("servicefee").value
    const buyGas = document.getElementById("buygas").value
    const sellGas = document.getElementById("sellgas").value
    const img = document.querySelector("img")
    let profitCal = ((100 - royalty - serviceFee) * 0.01) 
    profitCal = (sellPrice * profitCal) - buyPrice - buyGas - sellGas
    //no annoying 0.0000
    if (profitCal != 0) {
    netProfit.textContent = profitCal.toFixed(5)
    } else {
    netProfit.textContent = profitCal
    }
        if (profitCal >= 0.1) {
        img.style.display = "block"
        } else {
        img.style.display = "none"
        }
})
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Make sure your page has the button available

Comment: no errors. what do you mean has the button available? the button is visible and clickable in my code editor

Comment: Sorry, I mean make sure your page has a html button present

Comment: It could be that your JS is executing before the button loads, and the code  fails since it couldnt find the button

Comment: I think it might be it. do you have any suggestions on how to do it? the button is currently placed in the HTML file

Comment: You could wrap your code in a callback of `window.addEventListener('load', () => { /* code here */})`